# PHP Run Through Specified Number of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Working on a PHP order form.  I want to go through a list of arrays and print out similar to a foreach loop, but only for a specified number of arrays.

```
$PRODUCTS = array(
// product abbreviation, product name, unit price
// follow valid name/ID rules for product abbreviation 
array('prod1', '20"  4:3 (1600 x 1200)', 150),
array('prod2', '24" 16:9 (1920 x 1200)', 250),
array('prod3', '32" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 300),
array('prod4', '40" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 450),
array('prod5', '46" LCD 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 600),
array('prod6', '55" LCD 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 800),
array('prod7', 'Floor Stand (with rental of monitor only)', 100),
);

foreach($PRODUCTS as $product) {
    list($abbr, $name, $price) = $product;

    // quantity text input
    $qty_el = $frm->addInput('text', $abbr . '_qty', 0, 
        array('size'=>4, 'class'=>'cur', 'pattern'=>'[0-9]+', 'placeholder'=>0, 
              'onchange'=>'getProductTotal(this)',
              'onclick'=>'checkValue(this)', 'onblur'=>'reCheckValue(this)') );

    // total text input
    $tot_el = $frm->addInput('text', $abbr . '_tot', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') );

    // price hidden input
    $price_el = $frm->addInput('hidden', $abbr . '_price', $price);

    $tbl->addRow();
        $tbl->addCell($name);
        $tbl->addCell('$' . number_format($price, 2) . $price_el, 'cur' );
        $tbl->addCell( $qty_el, 'qty');
        $tbl->addCell( $tot_el );
}
```

how would I modify this to only print, for example, only the first 3 arrays?  The reason I'm looking to do this is to have a description header breaking up a few products in an order form - maybe there's a better way to do this?  I can provide more of the code if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to stop the loop after 3 loop of PRODUCTS array ?

Comment: Yeah, I can't really think of a better way to do it because I have everything in the PRODUCTS array feeding into a sum/totaling function so I don't want to make separate arrays.  But I want to stick headers between a few products.

Comment: use `break` statement to stop the loop. Check answer for update code.

Answer (score 0):

For few products, break the loop when it needs. Use php `break` to stop the loop. Here is your update code:

```
$PRODUCTS = array(
// product abbreviation, product name, unit price
// follow valid name/ID rules for product abbreviation 
array('prod1', '20"  4:3 (1600 x 1200)', 150),
array('prod2', '24" 16:9 (1920 x 1200)', 250),
array('prod3', '32" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 300),
array('prod4', '40" 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 450),
array('prod5', '46" LCD 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 600),
array('prod6', '55" LCD 16:9 (1920 x 1080)', 800),
array('prod7', 'Floor Stand (with rental of monitor only)', 100),
);

$i = 0;

foreach($PRODUCTS as $product) {
    list($abbr, $name, $price) = $product;

    // quantity text input
    $qty_el = $frm->addInput('text', $abbr . '_qty', 0, 
        array('size'=>4, 'class'=>'cur', 'pattern'=>'[0-9]+', 'placeholder'=>0, 
              'onchange'=>'getProductTotal(this)',
              'onclick'=>'checkValue(this)', 'onblur'=>'reCheckValue(this)') );

    // total text input
    $tot_el = $frm->addInput('text', $abbr . '_tot', 0, array('readonly'=>true, 'size'=>8, 'class'=>'cur') );

    // price hidden input
    $price_el = $frm->addInput('hidden', $abbr . '_price', $price);

    $tbl->addRow();
        $tbl->addCell($name);
        $tbl->addCell('$' . number_format($price, 2) . $price_el, 'cur' );
        $tbl->addCell( $qty_el, 'qty');
        $tbl->addCell( $tot_el );
  if($i==3){ //you can use any number
    break; 
  }$i++;
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to then pick up where the loop left off?  The more I think of this the more it seems I may have to manually write out each row.